# Insert a row every 3 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a duplicate row every 3rd row. Currently, the data looks like this, I am trying to add another row to make each block 4 instead of 3.

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
CCC
CCC
CCC
```

I'm new to vba, so I'm still trying to figure out how to avoid using .select, and apply methods to variables. My original code was super simple looping through offsets and copying and pasting. My dataset has 11000 rows so this takes quite a long time. Would love any advice, thanks!

Comment: Inserting is faster if you do it all at once. You can speed up copying and pasting by avoiding the clipboard. Directly assign values like `Range2.Value = Range1.Value`. You can do this with entire rows: `Rows(4).Value = Rows(3).Value`.

Comment: Turn off screen updating so the application can focus on executing the operations, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. Just don't forget to turn it back on when you're done or it'll look like the program froze. And you can turn off worksheet calculation while you're going, so formulas don't waste time recalculating while things are being moved around `Applictation.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. Again, don't forget to set it back to automatic or people will think their excel is broken.

Comment: Is there a way to directly assign values dynamically? Intead of directly naming the row?

Comment: of course! Take any contiguous collection of cells and assign values to them using any other similarly sized collection of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (**edited**)

```
Sub AddEvery3()
    Dim LR As Long, r As Long
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    r = 1
    Do
        Rows(r).Insert
        Cells(r, 1) = Cells(r + 1, 1)
        LR = LR + 1
        r = r + 4
    Loop While r <= LR
End Sub
```

Comment: By the time you get to the bottom, the last row will be > LR+1...

Comment: @TimWilliams I really inserti before the three rows and the code needs to go 1 more row down for the last insert

Comment: Every time you insert a row, the real last row increases by one.

Comment: @TimWilliams You are right. I've edited ;)

Comment: This is really useful, although it doesn't add entire row it just adds 1 cell. Is that a simple change like using .EntireRow